# Issue calling a function SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I created the following function to calculate distances between two points:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION [fnCalcDistanceKM](@lat1 FLOAT, @lat2 FLOAT, @lon1 FLOAT,       @lon2 FLOAT)
  RETURNS FLOAT 
  AS
  BEGIN

RETURN ACOS(SIN(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@lat2/180.0)+COS(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lon2/180.0-PI()*@lon1/180.0))*6371
END
```

But when I run the following select statement...I get the error:

Incorrect syntax near '13.077085'.

```
  select [fnCalcDistanceKM](13.077085,80.262675,13.065701,80.258916)
```

Comment: Boy, that function sure does look familiar!

Answer (score 2):

You should call it with schema name:

```
select dbo.[fnCalcDistanceKM](13.077085,80.262675,13.065701,80.258916)
```

> Scalar-valued functions must be invoked by using at least the two-part
>   name of the function. For more information about multipart names, see
>   Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL).

Comment: tried this...I get this error:    Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnCalcDistanceKM", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: You should specify the actual schema. See in which schema the function is created

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  SELECT * from [dbo].[fnCalcDistanceKM]13.077085,80.262675,13.065701,80.258916)